# ClickOnce: Unable to find a parent web from which to inherit authoring permissions

Tags: .net, winforms, iis, deployment, clickonce

I am trying to deploy a winforms app through ClickOnce on a website.
I have a VPN connection between my dev machine and the server.

When I run the publish process, I get this error in VS2008:

> Failed to connect to
>   'http://X.X.X.X/WebsiteName/Publish/'
>   with the following error: Unable to
>   create the Web site
>   'http://X.X.X.X/WebsiteName/Publish/'.
>   Server error: Unable to find a parent
>   web from which to inherit authoring
>   permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this time.

It was a Frontpage configuration issue.